# Decode Byte to String Python 3 for TIF metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte, tiff

For a .tif file, I've received bytes in one of its tag fields. How could I convert it to a string? 
The bytes field looks likse below: 
b'\x1c\x01Z\x00\x03\x1b%G\x1c\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00\x04\x1c\x02\x19\x00\tAustralia\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x02WA\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x11Western_America\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x05fauna\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x06People\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x05slide\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x0fmammal trapping '

I've tried my_string.decode("utf-8") or my_string.decode("latin-1") and my_string.decode("ascii"). None of them works.

They all gave me a string like below: 
'\x1c\x01Z\x00\x03\x1b%G\x1c\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00\x04\x1c\x02\x19\x00\tAustralia\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x02WA\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x11Western_America\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x05fauna\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x06People\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x05slide\x1c\x02\x19\x00\x0fmammal '

How Could I convert it and get something similar to "Western_America; mammal".

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Three questions: 1) Which libraries (if any) are you using to get the tag from the .tif file? 2) Can you tell what TIFF tag this is? That might provide a clue to its structure. 3) Can you provide the original .tif image for us to try to process ourselves?

Comment: Please don't paste images of code (or data or output). Post the actual content rather than just images. Also -- what does "none of them works" *mean*? Please be specific.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't want to write it by hand... `b'\x1c\x01Z\x00\x03\x1b%G\x1c\x02\x00\x00\x02\x02\x04\x1c\x02\x19\x00\tAustralia\x1c'`

Comment: Also, what do you mean it doesn't work? What are you expecting to get? Are you seeing an exception, or do you just see the bytes output without any "proper decoding"?

Comment: @MatthewCole 1) I'm using the tifffile package to get the tag from the .tif file. 2) The tag name for this field is 'IPTCNAA'. 3) I need the approval to provide to the public.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for the advice. I' ve edited it to get rid of the image.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb Thanks for your advice. I've edited my question, and hopefully, it becomes more clear now.

Comment: As a first step -- you need to understand just what those non-ascii bytes are doing there. You seem to assume that they correspond to encoded text, but I don't see why (since tiff is overall a binary format). I don't think that there is any shortcut to looking at the [tiff format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) in detail. Perhaps something like the python image library (or pillow) could help you there.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, I've actually tried pillow before but I couldn't find this field in its info. This piece of information is also presented in its Properties -> Detailed -> Description -> Tags. I would like to extract and save it in a spreadsheet for my .tif files.

Comment: I don't know -- but I added a `tiff` tag since that seems to be what the question is really about.

Comment: It can bo something more than only string. For example `\x02` before `WA` is equal to `len("WA")`. `\x11` before `Western_America` is equal to `len('Western_America")`. etc. SO there can be some structure of data, not only text.

Comment: for `"IPTC-NAA"` I found this [IPTC Metadata Structure](https://help.accusoft.com/ImageGear-Net/v22.1/Windows/HTML/topic371.html)

Comment: @furas Except `len("Western_America") == 15 (0xF)`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you are right. But it is still true for `\x05fauna`, `\x06People`, `\x05slide`

Comment: @furas Also, 0x19 == 25, which is the `Keyword` type in the structure link you posted.